# Can't add weblogic 14.1.1.0. server to eclipse

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I am trying to integrate eclipse 2021-12 as Oracle WebLogic Server 14.1.1.0. Both are installed and working perfectly separately. When trying to integrate and add a new weblogic server I get the message:

> The server is invalid. Error occurred reading server credential. If the domain was recreated, the server instance in Eclipse must also be recreated. Required classpath for credential detection is missing. Detection is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The server is invalid. Error occurred reading server credential. If the domain was recreated, the server instance in Eclipse must also be recreated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75279875/the-server-is-invalid-error-occurred-reading-server-credential-if-the-domain-w)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Eclipse OEPE version https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/oepe-v12219-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it changing the JDK used by eclipse at eclipse.ini setting a SDK 11 and commenting -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17.

[image]