# The server is invalid. Error occurred reading server credential. If the domain was recreated, the server instance in Eclipse must also be recreated

Tags: oracle, weblogic11g

Could any one help me on this.
I'm going to use the Oracle Weblogic server in Eclipse.
Use jdk 1.6.45 version

```
The server is invalid. Error occurred reading server credential. If the domain was recreated, the server instance in Eclipse must also be recreated. weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: weblogic.security.internal.encryption.EncryptionServiceException: [Security:090219]Error decrypting Secret Key java.lang.SecurityException: Crypto-J is disabled, a self-integrity check failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and it was because of the environment variable.
If you have installed a recent version of java it may have been modified.
The error is most likely caused by WebLogic not using the correct version of java due to the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Check your system environment variable and what version of java you use.

I had jdk_1.8.202, and I solved it by changing it to jdk_1.7.0_80

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, it was my case, the JAVA_HOME system environment variable did not match my version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Add java home in eclipse.ini

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jdkxxxxx\bin